# How to use multi-value, full calendar date picker in node form?

Tags: 7, forms, datetime

Users previously reported vehicle use in an Excel sheet formatted to look like a full month calendar. Clicked cells in the "calendar" marked visual x's (via macro) on days they used a vehicle, and cleared the cell if clicked again.

Converting to a Drupal node form now requires three times more clicks for every day. The 'dates used' field as multi-value (not always a contiguous date range), so they have to:

- click in the text box to launch the jQuery date picker
- click one of the days they used a vehicle
- click to add a new date field
- click one of the days they used a vehicle
- etc.

If they have 10 days to report, it takes 29 clicks! Yes, it's a 1WP, but it is poor UX compared to ye olde Excel file, where 10 days took 10 clicks.

Need a full calendar UI date picker in node form. Not the jQuery popup calendar, and actual full calendar display (such as you'd get with Calendar module display), and clicking on days records those days in the node's date field.

Essentially a full calendar widget is needed. There are many node display calendars, but none in entry form that are not a popup. Tried availability calendars module, but it tracks dates in it's own way using votingapi, not interfacing with the Dates module. I need it to be saved as normal dates for later use in views and etc.

Ideas? Thanks in advance!