# Multiple date picker for date popup widget

Tags: 7, javascript, forms, datetime

I've been searching for a while, but didn't find any contribute module to store multiple date values picking them from only one date popup calendar widget, just a [2009 feature request for D6](https://drupal.org/node/613614).

In D7 I have some kind of "available days calendar" content type for appointments, where I save multiple date values per node via the date popup widget.
When I add a new node,  I have to choose "add another item" to add multiple days and select them one by one via the JQuery date popup calendar or fill them one by one in textfield: a very frustrating procedure for the end user, especially if you have to select many days per month (like said in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/how-to-use-multi-value-full-calendar-date-picker-in-node-form), without answers).

How could I hook my node form in order to have just one date popup calendar where I can pick multiple days? Probably it's just a JQuery-matter to improve usability. I've found some JQuery libraries like [MultiDatesPicker for jQuery UI](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/). Could I integrate it (or another) easily in Drupal? Do you know a good tutorial/post to do that?

Any suggestion appreciated! :-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/availability_calendars allows to pick a date range but I think it doesn't use date fields under the hood.